# Exceeded the prepaid gas error while doing cross contract calls

Tags: nearprotocol

This is my code for cross contract calls:

```rust
const NO_DEPOSIT: Balance = 0;
const GAS: Gas = 25_000_000_000_000; 

#[ext_contract(ext_erc20)]
pub trait ExtErc20 {
    fn get_total_supply(&self) -> U128;
}
```

Function call:

```rust
pub fn get_total_supply_erc20(&self, erc20_id: AccountId) -> Promise {
    ext_erc20::get_total_supply(&erc20_id, NO_DEPOSIT, GAS)
}
```

Javascript code:

```js
const data = await nearvar.contract.get_total_supply_erc20({"erc20_id": "dev-1608541613194-2197959"})
console.log(data)
```

It gives "Exceeded the prepaid gas" error. I also tried with different gas values, but it didn't work.

Fungible token, get total supply:

```rust
pub fn get_total_supply(&self) -> U128 {
    self.total_supply.into()
}
```

[Code files](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmafQeo79RAbbu61y8Pv9dX8mUG5pUVBBXahoyPqqtfKvi/components/CrossContract/CrossContract.jsx)

Comment: can you increase the gas in this call: `const data = await nearvar.contract.get_total_supply_erc20({"erc20_id": "dev-1608541613194-2197959"})` is there a gas parameter there?

Comment: Adding gas parameter does not work.

Comment: can you post a github repo reproducing the error? we have to see what get_total_supply is doing

Comment: https://github.com/amiyatulu/avrit_ui/blob/master/contract/src/avrit.rs#L971 Here is the get_total_supply.

Answer (score 1):

Check this please: I would need to create a working example to be sure, but off the top of my head I think the problem is the following:

Be aware that you can get a "Exceeded the prepaid gas" error, with almost no execution.
Let's say you make the call from the client to `get_total_supply_erc20` with 50TGas limit, and in the called fn code you have:

```
const GAS = 51*TGAS;
pub fn get_total_supply_erc20(&self, erc20_id: AccountId) -> Promise {
    ext_erc20::get_total_supply(&erc20_id, NO_DEPOSIT, GAS)
}
```

You'll get an "Exceeded the prepaid gas" error, *but not because consumption*, it will be because the Promise engine can't reserve 51*Tgas for the promise call because the client-call has only 50Tgas limit.
It does not matter if the real consumption is 2 or 3 TGas for both functions.

Comment: I changed the value in both ways, in client side as well in contract, both didn't work. Let me try again.